# Availability of taxi from Tbilisi Airport to a certain hotel during winter

Tags: hotels, airport-transfer, taxis, tbilisi

I am planning to spend a winter in Tbilisi this December.  I would like to know if the taxi is available 24 hours at winter? Is there any website where I can book a car/shuttle to bring me to the hotel from the airport?

Comment: Because of it's unusual location between Europe, Russia, and Asia, many flights arrive late at night around 3am / 4am. I think taxi drivers are aware of this. I don't recall there being any shuttle companies though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, taxis are available 24/7. A simple Google search revealed:

http://www.tbilisiairport.com/en-EN/Transportation/Pages/Taxi.aspx

Also:

http://www.info-tbilisi.com/usefulinfos/taxi/

You can book [at least one service](http://www.concordmotors.ge/portal/alias__concordmotors/lang__en/tabid__967/default.aspx) online, but it appears to be just the equivalent of a paper form.

Perhaps your best bet is this:

http://www.airport-transfer.ge/